# Javascript - Change DIV background on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to expand and contract DIV's when an arrow is clicked. The arrow should point up/down depending on if the DIV has been expanded.

I have tried this but doesn't seem to be working. The arrow stays as the default down arrow. The slideup/down works fine, but the image doesn't change. Can anyone explain why?

```
         function toggle_visibility(id) {
             $e = $("#" + id);
             $arrow = $("#arrow" + id);

             if ($e.is(':visible')){
                 $e.slideUp("slow");
                 $arrow.css('background-image', 'url(../images/downarrow.png)');
             }else{
                $e.slideDown("slow");
                 $arrow.css('background-image', 'url(../images/uparrow.png)');
             }
         }
```

Comment: No Need `var $e = $(document.getElementById(id));` just use var $e = $("#"+id);

Comment: first of all `$e = $("#" + id);`

Comment: Thanks, just copied some code I found. Not too familiar with JS

Comment: `$(e)` ? Perhaps `$e`

Comment: you may be targeting the wrong element for the background

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yep you were right, I updated the code as above, but still no cigar

Comment: provide jsffidle please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
         $e = $("#"+id);

         if ($e.is(':visible')){
             $e.slideUp("slow");
             $e.css('background-image', 'url(../images/downarrow.png)');
         }else{
            $e.slideDown("slow");
             $e.css('background-image', 'url(../images/uparrow.png)');
         }
     }
```

Comment: I realised that I didn't have an ID on the arrow divs. I added id="arrow1" etc, but still no luck with it.

Comment: I added ID's to the arrows, and also the image path didnt need the "../" so I removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/9YA67/

```
<div id="arrow">Hello</div>

toggle_visibility($('#arrow'));

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var $element = $(id);

    if ($element.is(':visible')) {
        $element.slideUp("slow");
        $element.css('background-image', 'url(../images/downarrow.png)');
    } else {
        $element.slideDown("slow");
        $element.css('background-image', 'url(../images/uparrow.png)');
    }
}
```

Update: classes could come handy in this situation. as it would be more readable and keep CSS out of javascript.

updated fiddle with classes: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/9YA67/1/

```
toggle_visibility($('#arrow'));

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var $element = $(id);

    if ($element.is(':visible')) {
        $element.addClass("down").removeClass("up");
    } else {
        $element.addClass("up").removeClass("down");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your this syntex is wrong

```
$(e).css('background-image', 'url(../images/downarrow.png)');
```

replace it with this

```
$e.css('background-image', 'url(../images/downarrow.png)');
```

Comment: my bad didn't see the spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

`$(e).css(...)` should be `$e.css(...)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @n1ckolas It's not criticizing, it's pointing out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var $e = $("#"+id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting any value via the css('attributename','attributevalue') function in jQuery will add that attribute to the inline style of the element. In the inspector its often labeled element.style

Apart from the answers being posted, I would prefer you to do this via classes only, then you can create a separate class with the alternate background image in and switch classes by adding/removing classes from the element, this would not appear in the element.style, rather it would just switch the class and that would be displayed in the inspector instead.